# New to blender trying to figure out how to make a text have a cylindrical side shape

Tags: modeling, mesh

Hello I am trying to add a cylindrical side shape to a 3d text. I am trying to remove all of the parts outside of the cylinder as shown in this picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for a Boolean operation.

1. Convert your text to mesh (Object -> Convert to .. -> Mesh). This is important! Maybe make a copy of your text object first.
2. Add the modifier "Boolean" to either object (text, in this case)
3. Change mode to "Intersection" and select the cylinder in the object dropdown
   [image]
4. Optionally: Apply [CTRL]+[A] the modifier and delete unused objects.